# Python MySQLdb SELECT not returning proper value

Tags: python, mysql-python

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
poljeID = int(cursor.execute("SELECT poljeID FROM stanje"))
xkoord = cursor.execute("SELECT xkoord FROM polje WHERE poljeID = %s;", poljeID)
ykoord = cursor.execute("SELECT ykoord FROM polje WHERE poljeID = %s;", poljeID)

print xkoord, ykoord
```

It's a snippet from it, basically what it needs to do is fetch the ID of the field (poljeID) where an agent is currently on (stanje) and use it to get the x and y coordinates of that field (xkoord, ykoord).

The initial values for the variables are:

```
poljeID = 1
xkoord = 0
ykoord = 0
```

The values that I get with that code are:

```
poljeID = 1
xkoord = 1
ykoord = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should't do database work in your application. Use `SELECT xkoord, ykoord FROM polje WHERE poljeID IN (SELECT poljeID FROM stanje)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.execute` does not return the result of the query, it returns the number of rows affected. To get the result, you need to do `cursor.fetchone()` (or `cursor.fetchall()`) for each query.

(Note, really the second and third queries should be done at once: `SELECT xkoord, ycoord FROM ...`)

Comment: Changed it to `cursor.execute("SELECT xkoord, ykoord FROM polje WHERE poljeID = %s;", poljeID)

xkoord, ykoord = cursor.fetchone()` and it works now. Thanks!